# How can you tell whether an fd refers to inside or the outside of a pseudoterminal?

Tags: c, unix, pty

On at least Linux and NetBSD, `isatty` returns true for fds open on either the inside (`/dev/pts/0`, `/dev/ttyp0`, etc) or the outside (`/dev/ptmx`, `/dev/ptyp0`, etc) of a pseudoterminal, and all of the `tcgetxxx` operations I can conveniently test also fail to distinguish.  You can, in principle, tell by calling `fstat` and then looking at `st_rdev`, but then you have to know which device numbers are used for what, and that's not consistent across systems.

Is there a portable way, given an arbitrary open fd for which `isatty` returns true, to tell whether it refers to the outside of a pseudoterminal? Pseudoterminals are only sketchily specified in POSIX, so I do not think there is any *standard* way, but I'm hoping there's a way that works on the current generation of open-source Unixes at least, without having to compile a table of device numbers per supported OS.

(This would be used for an `lsof`-like inspection tool, in case you're wondering why I want to know.)

Comment: According to man ioctl_tty on linux, the TIOCPKT ioctl can only be applied to the master side of a pseudotty; otherwise, you get ENOTTY. I haven't tested it or anything.

Comment: Note: I have intentionally used the terms "outside" and "inside" for what most documentation of pseudoterminals calls "master" and "slave" respectively, as I think this is clearer conceptually. Please do not change this.

Comment: 'Twasn't me, guv. But I do think that while you might find the terms "inner" and "outer" more conceptually satisfying, the terms "master" and "slave" are in common use and it might have been helpful for those of us familiar with those terms and not so familiar with Zack's concepts to put them in parentheses. Of course, in this case it was really only necessary to understand that there is a bijection between the two terminologies, and I didn't feel the need to figure out what it is. So perhaps specifying it is unnecessary.

Comment: Not sure about others but "inside" and "outside" are really confusing to me. PTY master and slave are like two endpoints which are not *inside* and *outside*.

Comment: @EmilyE. That is bizarre to me.  To me, the asymmetry between the two sides of a pseudoterminal seems _exactly_ captured by "inside" and "outside".  The processes belonging to the session whose controlling terminal is the pty have the inside fd open, and the process responsible for capturing terminal I/O and forwarding it to the screen or the network tunnel or whatever works with the outside fd.  Why does it seem an inappropriate analogy to you?

Comment: Could you give a few other references where it's called "inside" and "outside" which I may take a look at?

Answer (score 3):

According to [`ptsname` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ptsname.3.html):

> **`char *ptsname(int fd);`**
>
> The `ptsname()` function returns the name of the **slave** pseudoterminal device corresponding to the **master** referred to by `fd`.

And it will fail with `ENOTTY` if

> `fd` does not refer to a pseudoterminal **master** device.

So you can first call `isatty()` and then `ptsname()`.

And `ptsname()` is

> CONFORMING TO POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008.